# My `req.body` is passing undefined values so my db is not updating with the fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My req.body gives me null value.How can I get the values so that I can store it in the db.So when I am refreshing the page the data gets away because the fields are not present in the db.

`.js file`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var cors = require('cors');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactlist');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());


app.use(function(req,res,next){

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

var contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    number:Number,
    address:String
});

var Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);


//Routers
//get
app.get('/contacts',function(req,res){
    console.log('inside get router fetching the contacts');

    Contact.find(function(err, contacts){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(contacts);
    });

});

//post---->get

app.post('/contacts',function(req,res){
    console.log('creating the contacts');
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.number || !req.body.address){
        // res.render('show_message', {message: "Sorry, you provided worng info"});
        console.log('information not provided'); 
        console.log(req.body.name);  //undefined
         console.log(req.body.email); //undefined
          console.log(req.body.number); //undefined
    }
    else{

    Contact.create({
        name:req.body.name,    
        email:req.body.email,
        number:req.body.number,
        address:req.body.address,
        done: false
    },function(err,contact){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);

        Contact.find({},function(err,contact){
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(contact);
        });
    });
    }
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('App listening on port 8080');
```

`home.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ContactsService } from '../../providers/contacts';
import { AddContactPage } from '../add-contact-page/add-contact-page';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  contacts: any;

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController, public contactsService: ContactsService, public nav: NavController  ) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('inside ion view did load function');
    this.contactsService.getContacts().then(data => {
      console.log('inside Homepage get call', data);//object
      this.contacts = data;
    });
  }
  save() {
    console.log('inside save function');
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddContactPage);
    modal.onDidDismiss(contact => {
      if (contact) {
        console.log('The new contacts that has to be added are', contact);//real data***
        this.contacts.push(contact);
        this.contactsService.createContacts(contact);
      }
    });
    modal.present();

  }
}
```

`add-contact-page.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the AddContactPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-contact-page',
  templateUrl: 'add-contact-page.html',
})
export class AddContactPage {
  name:any;
  email:any;
  number:number;
  address:any;

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }


  addContact(){
    console.log('you have clicked addContact()');
    let contact = {
       name: this.name,
       email:this.email,
       number:this.number,
       address:this.address

    };
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(contact);
    console.log('The data is', this.name, this.email, this.number, this.address);
  }
close(){
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}

}
```

In home.ts file there is a modal when I click onadd button which has save() as a handler, the add-contact-page gets diplayed as a modal window.There I add name, email,number,address and click on addContact button handler.

`.service class`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the Contacts provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ContactsService {
  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Contacts Provider');
    this.data = null;
  }

  getContacts() {
    if (this.data) {

      return Promise.resolve(this.data);

    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/contacts').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log('inside get contactsService', this.data);//only objects
        resolve(this.data);
      });

    });
  }

  createContacts(contact) {
    console.log('inside create contact service class', contact);//this is correctly displaying the data
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/contacts', JSON.stringify(contact)).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('inside createContacts function in service class ', res.json());//only objects
      console.log('contact in json',+JSON.stringify(contact) );//Nan
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: seems there's nothing wrong in the code, i am thinking maybe the consumer is passing an empty request. have you tried invoking the endpoint using postman?

Comment: What is being sent as the POST request from the browser?  Is it a form? Or JSON?  Have you checked the network tab in the browser debugger to see exactly what is being sent from the browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 shall I show you the frontend code? It is a JSON.

Comment: response is empty in the network

Comment: Yes, you should include the relevant front-end code.  Your first task is to figure out if the client is sending what you expect or not so you know whether the problem is in the client or server.

Comment: I have added the code please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Srvice class post method I have not passed the `contact` object,So It would be like this:

`this.http.post('url', contact, {headers:headers}).subscribe(res=>{console.log(res.json());`

Answer (score 0):

Since it display on the console I will suggest you remove **`JSON.stringify`**

```
 console.log('inside create contact service class', contact);//this is correctly displaying the data
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/contacts', JSON.stringify(contact)).subscribe(res => {
```